# Multi Level Pretty URL for E-Commerce Products In htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Updated Version**
I am developing an E-commerce portal where the products need to be shown with a pretty url and also under categories.

**My Current Link:** http://abcd.xyz/products.php?pro_tag=1221212112 (FAKE LINK)

**My Goal:** http://abcd.xyz/products/1221212112 (FAKE LINK)

My Current HTACCESS CODE. (Made it with the help of other Stackoverflow Suggestions) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ products.php?pro_tag=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ products.php?pro_tag=$2&ctg=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

**Figured out the problem: 'pro_tag' isn't being fetched. Need help to fix that.**

Comment: Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Yes. When i am using the link: http://abcd.xyz/1221212112, it is loading the data from the database along with some CSS issues, but when i am using my GOAL Link, it isn't loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ products.php?pro_tag=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ products.php?pro_tag=$2&ctg=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I add a `ctg` variable...

Comment: Nope! Doesn't Work !

Comment: Your `products.php` is in `products` directory ?

Comment: Nope! Its a normal products.php page in the index directory.

Comment: Just tested again with your code. Now even  abcd.xyz/1221212112 this link won't work. And my GOAL Link isn't working as well.

Comment: You try to use `http://abcd.xyz/products/1221212112` not `http://abcd.xyz/1221212112` !!! (In your question)

Comment: Where did you put the htaccess file ? In `/Products/` ?

Comment: http://abcd.xyz/products/1221212112 this is what i want to achieve. It isn't achieved using the code you provided.

Comment: No. I have put it in the index directory or the main directory where the index file resides.

Comment: That work with mine ! Did you clear your browser cache or try with other one ?

Comment: I just rechecked & tested with your code. I found out that the pro_tag isnt being fetched when i am using your provided code. Rest everything is working fine, just that the Pro_tag isnt being fetched. It is returning an empty value.

Comment: Yes. it isnt fetching the pro_tag.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what your problem is!